# Advice needed for populating historical postgresql table with multiple rows per date time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, insert

I have an SQL query that generates multiple rows for every hour with market information (one row per market) such as accumulated number of unique customers at that time from a table that looks like the following, followed by the query:

| organization_id | transaction_id | transaction_date_time | market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6789 | 80031 | 2021-06-07 15:33 | 3 |
| 6789 | 80032 | 2021-06-07 15:34 | 3 |
| 6789 | 80033 | 2021-06-07 15:44 | 3 |
| 6789 | 80034 | 2021-06-07 15:45 | 3 |
| 1234 | 80035 | 2021-06-17 14:07 | 1 |
| 1234 | 80036 | 2021-06-17 14:07 | 1 |
| 4321 | 80037 | 2021-07-05 11:51 | 2 |
| 4321 | 80038 | 2021-07-05 11:51 | 2 |
| 1234 | 80039 | 2021-07-13 15:41 | 1 |
| 1234 | 80040 | 2021-07-14 09:41 | 1 |
| 1234 | 80041 | 2021-07-14 09:55 | 1 |

```
    select
        date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) as "date_time"
        ,ct.country_code as market
        ,count(distinct ct.organization_id) acc_alltime_organizations
        ,count(distinct case when ct.transaction_date_time >= current_date - interval '30' day then ct.organization_id else null end) acc_1m_organizations
    from customer_transactions ct
    group by
            "date_time"
            ,market
```

Above is a sample of the table that I create (in reality there are more accumulations but that shouldn't change the setup drastically) for the current_timestamp. I would like these rows not only for the current timestamp but for each hour since for example `2016-01-01 10:00:00` until now. This means that for example I want to know that on `2018-09-09 00:00:00` there were 10000 accumulated organizations ever having used the product and 1000 unique organizations used the product in the month previous to that date.

A column with all hours that I need those rows for can be generated as follows:

```
select count(*)
from generate_series(
    (select date_trunc('hour', min(ct.transaction_date_time))
                from customer_transactions ct 
    ),
    current_date,
    interval '1 hour'
) as t("date_time")
)
```

The desired result looks something like the following table:

| date_time | Market | acc_alltime_organizations | acc_1m_organizations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 10:00 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2016-01-01 10:00 | 2 | 9 | 4 |
| 2016-01-01 10:00 | 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 2016-01-01 10:00 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| 2016-01-01 11:00 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2016-01-01 11:00 | 2 | 9 | 4 |
| 2016-01-01 11:00 | 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 2016-01-01 11:00 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| 2016-01-01 12:00 | 1 | 11 | 6 |
| 2016-01-01 12:00 | 2 | 10 | 5 |
| 2016-01-01 12:00 | 3 | 9 | 4 |
| 2016-01-01 12:00 | 4 | 8 | 3 |
| … | … | … | … |

So my thoughts were to loop over the hours generated with the code snippet above and replace the current_date in the first code snippet with a variable of date that can be looped through, and to insert into a new table the row per market per hour but I am stuck on how to implement that.

If there is another method than looping that is preferred then also please let me know :). Help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your first query is not syntactically correct (I think it is just missing a `group by`, but it is not clear what else might be missing).

Comment: You're right, I removed too much from the original query, I'll make sure to make it correct. I'll also add a bit of sample data, as much as I can :).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your original query:

```
select date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) as date_time,
       ct.country_code as market,
       count(distinct ct.organization_id) as acc_alltime_organizations,
       count(distinct case when ct.transaction_date_time >= current_date - interval '30' day then ct.organization_id end) as acc_1m_organizations
from customer_transactions ct
group by ct.country_code;
```

Then you can modify it for ranges of hours using:

```
select h.date_time,
       t.country_code as market,
       count(distinct ct.organization_id) as acc_alltime_organizations,
       count(distinct case when ct.transaction_date_time >= h.date_time - interval '30' day then ct.organization_id end) as acc_1m_organizations
from (select generate_series(min(ct.transaction_date_time), current_date, interval '1 hour') as date_time
      from customer_transactions ct
     ) h left join
     customer_transactions ct
     on ct.transaction_date_time <= h.date_time
group by h.date_time, ct.country_code
```

There may be more efficient ways to calculate what you want, but this answers the question that you have asked.  You might want to ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some more information on samples of the dataset I have and the desired result. I tried running your script and unfortunately it takes a really long time to run, even if I only run it for the past 3 hours (more than 500 seconds for that and counting) on a smaller development sample of the dataset. If you would be able to give some pointers to a more efficient solution that would be great. I don't mind the logic, as long as I get the result (somewhat) efficiently. Thanks!